# Testing if a user enter string is a palindrome using stacks

Tags: c++, stack

My professor wants us to write a program using stacks and queues to test whether a user-entered string is a palindrome. I think I've almost got it, but it keeps saying every word is a palindrome.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include "Palindrome.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Pal;
    cout << "Enter a palindrome: ";
    getline (cin, Pal);

    TestPal test;

    test.isPalindrome(Pal);



    return 0;
}
```

Palindrome.h

```
#ifndef PALINDROME_H
#define PALINDROME_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TestPal
{
    public: 
        int isPalindrome(string);
        TestPal();

};

#endif
```

Palindrome.c (I know just having .c is odd, our professor told us to label it like this)

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int TestPal::isPalindrome(string Pal)
{
    stack<char> Pstack;
    int length;
    int palSize = Pal.size();
    bool isPal;

    if(palSize > 0)
    {

        for(int i=0; i<palSize; i++)
        {
            Pstack.push(Pal[i]);
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= palSize; ++i)
    {
        if(Pstack.top() == Pal[palSize - i])
        {
            isPal = true;
            Pstack.pop();       
        }
        else
        isPal = false;
    }


  if(!isPal)
  {
    cout<< Pal << " is not a palindrome."<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<< Pal << " is a palindrome."<<endl;
  }

    //cout << palSize;

};

TestPal::TestPal()
{

};
```

Output

```
Enter a palindrome: Palindrome
Palindrome is a palindrome.

--------------------------------
Process exited after 12.39 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Might not solve the problem, but your `isPalindrome`-method is declared to return an `int` but nothing is returned.

Comment: Using a stack for palindrome checking is overkill and makes it a lot more complex than it has to be, but if it's an assignment: you should fill the stack only up to the center of the string (half of `Pal`). Then you start popping the stack and compare the top element to the 2nd half of `Pal`

Comment: Using a stack *and* a queue makes this very simple. (I suspect that the purpose of this exercise is that you understand the difference between them.)

Answer (score 1):

There were several errors in your code:

- Your isPalindrome didn't return a value. You have to return a value and do the check if this value is true or false in your main-function.
- When you see, that, for example the first character is not equal to the last one, you have to break out of your loop immediately, since when at least one character-pair is not equal, you don't have a palindrome, regardless how many of the following characters are equal.
- `Pstack.top()` returns the last character of your string. Therefore you have to compare it with the first one (`Pal[i]`) and not with the last one.
- The comparison won't work, if the first character is an uppercase letter and the last one not. Therefore, I have used the `tolower`-function to prevent this issue.
- The `if` around the first loop is unnecessary, since if the size is 0, the body of the `for`-loop won't be executed anyways.
- Further optimisation: In the second loop, it is sufficient to check the first half of the string.

### Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include "Palindrome.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string Pal;
    cout << "Enter a palindrome: ";
    getline(cin, Pal);

    TestPal test;

    if(test.isPalindrome(Pal)) {
        std::cout << Pal << " is a palindrome." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << Pal << " is not a palindrome." << std::endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

### Palindrome

```
#include "Palindrome.h"
#include "stack"
#include "queue"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int TestPal::isPalindrome(string Pal) {
    stack<char> Pstack;
    int palSize = Pal.size();

   for(int i = 0; i < palSize; i++) {
       Pstack.push(Pal[i]);
   }


    for(int i = 0; i < palSize / 2; ++i) {
        if(tolower(Pstack.top()) != tolower(Pal[i])) return false;

        Pstack.pop();
    }

      return 1;

};

TestPal::TestPal() {

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a palindrome checker using a stack and one without a stack. As you can see, the latter is much easier to read and understand.

```
bool isPalindrome(std::string const& str)
{
    std::stack<char> tokens;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++)    
        tokens.push(str[i]);

    for (std::size_t i = (str.size() + 1) / 2; i < str.size(); i++)    
    {
        if (tokens.top() != str[i])
            return false;
        tokens.pop();
    }   

    return true;
}

bool isPalindromeWithoutStack(std::string const& str)
{
    std::stack<char> tokens;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size() / 2; i++)
        if (str[i] != str[str.size() - 1 - i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Functionally, we push each character in the test string on the stack. We do that until we reach the center of our test string (the first for loop). After that, we start popping the stack and compare the popped character against the next character in the test string (the second for loop). The calculation of the starting index `(str.size() + 1) / 2` looks a bit odd, but this allows us to skip the character in the middle of the test string has an uneven length (and therefore the middle character has nothing to compare against).

The second version `isPalindromeWithoutStack` simply compares the i-th character to the i-th-from-the-end character.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/IL8EWz) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "My professor wants us to write a program *using stacks and queues*..."

As @molbdnilo says in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381228/testing-if-a-user-enter-string-is-a-palindrome-using-stacks#comment108586194_61381228), "I suspect that the purpose of this exercise is that you understand the difference between them."

One of the most powerful tools in designing an algorithm to solve a problem, is to *solve the problem yourself - on paper*. Grab a piece of paper and write "Stack" and "Queue" on it.

```
Stack   Queue
-----   -----
```

Now let's take the first letter of "palindrome" and add it to *both* structures:

```
Stack   Queue
-----   -----
  p       p
```

To add the second letter of palindrome, remember that it is pushed to the *top* of the stack (so you'll need to move the "p" down), but to the *end* of the queue:

```
Stack   Queue
-----   -----
  a       p
  p       a
```

The next letter in "palindrome" is "l" - add it to both structures:

```
Stack   Queue
-----   -----
  l       p
  a       a
  p       l
```

Do this for the rest of the word.

Once you're done --- try it again with with a word (or short phrase) that *is* a palindrome. What do you notice? If I gave you just the pieces of paper, how would you use them to decide which was a palindrome?

### P.S.

There *are* other (more efficient) ways of checking palindromes, but your prof has asked to use a stack *and* a queue for a specific reason.

Also - always remember that if you don't know how to do something - you can't teach a computer to do it. Conversely, once you have done something yourself (on paper), in small, easy to describe steps --- coding it up becomes much easier.

Programming consists of multiple steps. One is designing and understanding the algorithm. A separate step is writing the code to implement the algorithm. The first step can (and often does) take more time and effort than the second.

Spending more time with your hands off the keyboard then on the keyboard *is a good thing*<sup>TM</sup> :)